# Python Selenium "NameError: name 'driver' is not defined"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, nameerror

I try to run a webdriver Selenium and select

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

usernameStr = 'value'
passwordStr = 'value'


browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(('website'))

# fill in username and hit the next button

username = browser.find_element_by_id('username')
username.send_keys(usernameStr)

nextButton = browser.find_element_by_xpath('value')
nextButton.click()

# wait for transition then continue to fill items

username= WebDriverWait(browser, 2).until(
     EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, value')))
username.send_keys(usernameStr)

password = browser.find_element_by_id('value')
password.send_keys(passwordStr)


signInButton = browser.find_element_by_id('submitButton')
signInButton.click()

nextButton = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/app-root/div[2]/app-nav/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/button')
nextButton.click()


el = driver.find_element_by_id('reason')
for option in el.find_elements_by_value('16'):
```

Problem is that i try to select a value from a list. (Everyhting works until this point):

```
el = driver.find_element_by_xpath('reason')
for option in el.find_elements_by_value('16'):
```

Error:

```
"NameError: name 'driver' is not defined"
```

I'm pretty noob at this, so sorry if this is an easy solution.

Comment: Why switch from `browser` which you've been using all along to `driver`? Did you copy and paste the line with `driver` from somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, i'm failry noob at this. So the problem is that i have to use Select....?

Comment: Read my comment again slowly.

Comment: Aaaaahaaaaa! Now i got it! Browser.find_element etc.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
"NameError: name 'driver' is not defined"
```

...implies that in your program you are referring to `driver` which is not defined within your program.

---

### Details

You have initiated the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) instance and referenced to it as **`browser`** almost throughout your program.

But in the line:

```
el = driver.find_element_by_xpath('reason')
```

you are trying to refer to a the instance `driver` which is not defined within your program. Hence the error.

---

### Solution

Change `driver` to **`browser`**. So effectively your line of code will be:

```
el = browser.find_element_by_xpath('reason')
```